# What's the difference between calling pip as a command line command, and calling it as a module of the python command?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

When installing python modules, I seem to have two possible command line commands to do so.

`pip install {module}`

and

`py -{version} -m pip install {module}`

I suppose this can be helpful for selecting which version of python has installed which modules? But there's rarely a case where I wouldn't want a module installed for all possible versions.

Also the former method seems to have a pesky habit of being out-of-date no matter how many times I call:

`pip install pip --upgrade`

So are these separate? Does the former just call the latest version of the latter?

Comment: the  `-m `switch tells the python interpreter to run a module (pip in this case) as an executable

Comment: Note that a bare ``pip ...`` only installs the module for one version as well. On any OS using Python itself (Linux/MacOS/...) you should *never* manually install modules for the system Python – thus never wanting a module installed for all Python versions.

Comment: https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/

Comment: @AleksanderIkleiw I did no such thing.

Answer (score 3):

TLDR: Prefer `... -m pip` to always install modules for a specific Python version/environment.

---

The `pip` command executes the equivalent of `... -m pip`. However, bare `pip` does not allow to select *which* Python version/environment to install to – the first match in your executable search path is selected. This may be the most recent Python installation, a virtual environment, or *any other* Python installation.

Use the `... -m pip` variant in order to select the Python version/environment for which to install a module.

Answer (score 0):

So the `pip install module` is callable if you have already installed the `pip`. The `pip install pip --upgrade` upgrades the pip and if you replace the `pip` into a module name it will upgrade that module to the most recent one. the `py -{version} -m pip install {module}` is callable if you have installed many versions of python - for example most of the Linux servers got installed python 2, so when you install the Python 3, and you want to install a module to version 3, you will have to call that command.